# Migrate Objective-C Core Data to Swift Persistent Container

Tags: objective-c, swift, core-data, nspersistentcontainer

When Apple added the new PersistentContainer class, they changed the location of the data stores. That means that if you add a new PersistentContainer, it won't pick up the current database but create one.
The underlying issue is that the new store is inside another folder.
How can I specify the folder for a PersistentContainer so that it picks up the old store?

Answer (score 0):

The persistent store(s) of a `NSPersistentContainer` are specified in its `persistentStoreDescriptions` array property.  By default, it contains one persistent store of type SQLite, backed by a file in the `Application Support` folder of your app's container.

The procedure to change this is explained in the *Discussion* section of [the documentation of this property](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nspersistentcontainer/1640577-persistentstoredescriptions).

The path to the file of this store is specified in the `url` property of the that `NSPersistentStoreDescription`, which is mutable.  So you should set the `url` property of that single `NSPersistentStoreDescription` in that array to your desired path.